# Explanation of the output obtained in the following c program

Tags: c

Please tell how the main declared at the end of the program works out here and '\' use.Output s 0

```
#define P printf("%d\n", -1^~0);
#define M(P) int main()\
         {\
            P\
            return 0;\
         }
M(P)
```

Comment: The backslashes continue the `#define` statement into the next line.  It's how you write multiline `#define`s.

Answer (score 2):

After macro expansion this is equivalent to:

```
int main() { printf("%d\n", -1^~0); return 0; }
```

Then `~0` is `-1` in a two's complement system so  `-1 ^ ~0` is `-1 ^ -1` is `0` as xoring a number with itself gives `0`.

Comment: but m(p) is at the end of the program . i wanted to know what the '\' did here .

Comment: @RoyceRaju It's the line-continuation character for the preprocessor.

Comment: @RoyceRaju the `\\` is used as a standard line separator in a macro definition.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with `gcc` and adding the `-E` option (i.e., stop after preprocessing and output preprocessed code), reveals what's happening:

```
# 1 "output.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "output.c"


int main() { printf("%d\n", -1^~0); return 0; }
```

Basically you are just printing an integer: `-1^~0`.

This is equivalent to `-1 XOR 0xFFFFFFFF` (assuming that integers are on 32 bits here), which, since the two's complement of `1` (i.e., representation of `-1`) is `0xFFFFFFFF`, always outputs `0` (`1 XOR 1 == 0`).

Answer (score 1):

by preprocessor your code will expands to:

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", -1^~0);
  return 0;
}
```

`~0` is 1's complement of `0` in this all bits are `1` (in most implementation).

```
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111   <== ~0 , compliment each bit
```

So suppose if you have 32-bit int:

`-1` is 2'c complement of `1` in this also all bits are one:

```
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001   <== 1
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110   <== 1's complement of 1 
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111   <== 2's complement of 1
```

So `-1^ ~0`  **ouputs:**  `0`

because in `^` is `XOR`- operator and `1 xor 1 = 0`.

```
~0       ==   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111   
-1       ==   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
            ------------------------------------------- Bitwise XOR
~0 ^ -1  ==   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

check [here how XOR works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`gcc -E <file_name>.c`

> **-E**  Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link

Output:

```
int main() { printf("%d\n", -1^~0); return 0; }
```